# PHP Array comparison: why must the callback function for array_uintersect return -1, 0, or 1?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

It's noted in a comment on the docs for [array_uintersect](http://php.tonnikala.org/manual/el/function.array-uintersect.php#72841) that the callback function MUST return either -1 ($a < $b), 0 ($a === $b), or 1 ($a > $b)

The callback function's purpose is to compare $a and $b to determine whether to include them in the intersection, or exclude them. So why return -1, 0, or 1 instead of a simple boolean?

Here is some (working) [example code](http://3v4l.org/ENYof) of what I wanted to achieve, I'm just curious why it works that way.

Comment: But why are three values required?

Comment: I think those 3 conditions are used by some kind of internal sorting considering `-1`, `0` and `1` are actually typical sorting criteria.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider this particular case.

Comment: In this case, only two values are needed: whether a value is present in the other array or not. The sort functions do need to know whether one value is different because it's larger or smaller. To avoid having two kinds of callbacks with different semantic, they just make array_uintersect() use the same type as usort().

Comment: Maybe they just want to be consistent with respect to array sorting functions. *edit*: basically what cleong said ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is important to mention that `array_uintersect()` operates even *more* strangely on your array inputs than one would hope for. One expects that calling `array_uintersect($firstArray, $secondArray, function ($a, $b) {})` would result in each entry from `$firstArray` and each entry from `$secondArray` to be compared once each (with the optimization of stopping comparisons for an entry after the first intersection is found). Any sane person would expect that each entry of `$firstArray` would land in the callback's `$a` argument and each entry of `$secondArray` would land in its `$b` argument.

This is *not* the case! Believe it or not, php's first call to your callback has `$a` and `$b` **both set to entries from `$firstArray`**! You're calling a function named after the intersection of arrays, but that function also compares the entries in your individual arrays rather than simply comparing between arrays. It's mind-numbing, really.

Thus, `array_uintersect` is **not** a replacement for the following block. Users beware.

```
$intersection = [];
foreach ($firstArray as $a) {
    foreach ($secondArray as $b) {
        if (user_compare_function($a, $b) === 0) {
            $intersection[] = $a;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in simple words, under what situations does `array_uintersect()` give a different result than your codes above?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is in the PHP Source `usort` and `array_uintersect` and other similar user callback compare function which is `php_array_user_compare`

`xref: /PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c`

```
568static int php_array_user_compare(const void *a, const void *b TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
569{
570    Bucket *f;
571    Bucket *s;
572    zval **args[2];
573    zval *retval_ptr = NULL;
574
575    f = *((Bucket **) a);
576    s = *((Bucket **) b);
577
578    args[0] = (zval **) f->pData;
579    args[1] = (zval **) s->pData;
580
581    BG(user_compare_fci).param_count = 2;
582    BG(user_compare_fci).params = args;
583    BG(user_compare_fci).retval_ptr_ptr = &retval_ptr;
584    BG(user_compare_fci).no_separation = 0;
585    if (zend_call_function(&BG(user_compare_fci), &BG(user_compare_fci_cache) TSRMLS_CC) == SUCCESS && retval_ptr) {
586        long retval;
587
588        convert_to_long_ex(&retval_ptr);
589        retval = Z_LVAL_P(retval_ptr);
590        zval_ptr_dtor(&retval_ptr);
591        return retval < 0 ? -1 : retval > 0 ? 1 : 0;
592    } else {
593        return 0;
594    }
595}
```

This uses `retval` which is an integer to compare the function if you look at

```
retval < 0 ? -1 : retval > 0 ? 1 : 0
```

If you are using using Boolean and conversion is required it can only give `0` or `1`

Example

```
var_dump((int) true); // 1
var_dump((int) false); // 0
```

This means that you might be able to get away with `boolean` during intersect because only where `$a === $b = 0` is required but not for other implementations where  `retval < 0`

Comment: you dont get away with bool`function myfunction($v1,$v2){
if ($v1===$v2) return 0;
//if ($v1 > $v2) return 1;//uncomment this to see the correct result
else           return -1;
}

$a1=array(2,4,1);
$a2=array(3,1,4);
print_r(array_uintersect($a1,$a2,"myfunction"));`

Answer (score 1):

the [pear replacement](http://pear.php.net/reference/PHP_Compat-latest/__filesource/fsource_PHP_Compat__PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3CompatFunctionarray_uintersect.php.html) accepts callbacks, that return only a boolean.
the php function does not.
so the reason is probably an optimization in php. you might check this [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c)

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, is a call to the C function `zend_qsort`.

```
if (behavior == INTERSECT_NORMAL) {
    zend_qsort((void *) lists[i], hash->nNumOfElements, sizeof(Bucket *), intersect_data_compare_func TSRMLS_CC);
} else if (behavior & INTERSECT_ASSOC) { /* triggered also when INTERSECT_KEY */
    zend_qsort((void *) lists[i], hash->nNumOfElements, sizeof(Bucket *), intersect_key_compare_func TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

[Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is sensitive to these relations so that it can perform the partition component of it's algorithm.  Items with the same value as the *pivot* are placed adjacent to, and on either side of the *pivot*.

Interesting that the greater than comparison operator `>` works for object comparison, something of an undocumented behavior.  According to one comment, PHP looks at the values of public objects for this comparison.  This is actually [a discussion point on the internals list](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg61823.html) right now!